# subprocess.Popen breaks terminal on exit

Tags: linux, python-3.x, subprocess, i3

I am try trying to use python to open a program.  My goal is to have the terminal available to me after python launches the subprocess.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['feh', 'foo.png']) # locks program until I close the image = no go
subprocess.Popen('feh', 'foo.png']) # works but breaks new line in terminal
```

In the terminal, I have to run

```
$ stty sane
```

to fix, but I cannot see what I'm typing...

I have tried adding this to the end of my program:

```
import atexit
def fixTerm():
    subprocess.run(['stty', 'sane'])
atexit.register(fixTerm)
```

but no joy.  the  program still breaks terminal on exit (or hanges if I use .run()

I have experienced this issue on multiple linux platforms, currently trying to flex and use Arch Linux & i3

other trys with no joy:

```
subprocess.Popen(['feh', 'foo.png'], shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(['feh', 'foo.png'], shell=False)
subprocess.Popen(['feh', 'foo.png'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Not sure what to try next.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the entire program that breaks the terminal.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import subprocess

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
plt.plot(x, x**2, label='quadratic')

plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
p = subprocess.Popen(['feh', 'foo.png'])
```

I'm not sure what the diference is between this, and what "A. Albershteyn"'s solution is, but that does not cause the issue, and the above program does.

Comment: Can you describe your use case in a little bit more details; why do you want to run program from python and then use the terminal? Maybe we could find a better solution with this information

Comment: feh is a graphics viewer.  my program will open a picture as it's last action.  I do not want to lock myself out of the console the entire time that picture is open.  Note the main python program has closed, but the child process opening feh is still running.  Whether I close the graphic right away or continue working I have to clean up my console using $ stty sane   .  Not what I want to do every time I run this program

Answer (score 0):

Works for me just fine, no output of the `feh`. What do you mean by "breaks new line"?

```
~ 
➔ python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['feh', '42.png'])"

~ 
➔ echo "feh is open"
feh is open

~ 
➔ echo "I closed it"
I closed it

~ 
➔
```

Comment: I ran your examples in the terminal and they did not cause the terminal no-new-line issue.  IE it worked great.  I edited my original post to show the program that does cause issue.  I don't see what would cause issue in my program if it works fine in yours?

Comment: @posop your example is working fine for me. Python script frees terminal and `feh` stays open; when I close it doesn't cause any newlines. How do you run your script?